# db2 query bad grammar, how to run unit test with h2

Tags: junit, db2, h2, spring-boot-test

Two-part question here with the following db2 query in mind:

```
select col1!!col2 from table1
```

1. I had never seen a double exclamation mark (`!!`) operator. From the results it returns, it appears to be doing a simple concatenation of col1 and col2. I've looked online in the db2 documentation but haven't been able to find a definition. Can someone please verify?
2. I am not allowed to change the query to use a different syntax and I would like to be able to run a unit test with an h2 in memory database for this query and other queries that have some db2 quirks. How can I achieve this with junit4?

Comment: Look again at the original code, the double `||` (pipe symbol) is the concatenation operator, for Db2 not the exclamation point.

Comment: @mao No, it's a double exclamation point, not a double pipe. I've tested the query against the actual db2 database and it works.

Comment: What is the Db2-server platform (z/os,  i-series,  linux/unix/windows/cloud)?  And which tool do you use to submit the SQL ?

Comment: It can happen on IBM i with some CCSID that `!!` operator replaces `||` (e.g. 290 Japan Katakana), maybe z/os too (don't know what to do in your case)

Comment: Double exclamation point doesn't work. See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=6a76270efa12aec3d6b493682cc9e82b

Comment: @TheImpaler The double exclamation point does work on some versions of db2. That's only one part of the question, even if I were allowed to sub it with some other expression, how would the h2 mock database be configured for them? For example another db2 feature is ^ for negation: ^< would be "not less than", equivalent to "greater than or equal to" but if I can't change the actual query, is there another way to get h2 to cooperate?

Comment: @geco17 I consider H2 great database for its size. However, you can really emulate DB2, Oracle, or PostgreSQL only up to a degree. In my dev sandbox I currently have several vms with DB2, and also I run DB2 docker images locally. That's the only way to actually run the queries the same way they'll run in PROD; they run a bi slower than in PROD, but I get full syntax validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up solving this problem is perhaps a bit ugly but it was the best I could do within the limits I had:

- can't use a docker container for a test instance of the actual db2 database
- can't directly modify the queries defined in the source files

In my unit tests I did the following:

1. set up spy beans on the service methods that returned the raw queries
2. created `when` conditions on the spy beans such that instead of returning a query that I knew wouldn't work (as per the examples, stuff with `!!`, `^<`, etc), the `when` conditions would return *equivalent* queries with an h2-compatible syntax (`||`, `>=`, etc)
3. queried the h2 database with the modified query

Hopefully this can help someone.